# Why is this Windows Batch script not able to find the program net.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm creating what was meant to be a very simple batch script to map a drive based on user input and check that the drive doesn't already exist first.

```
@echo off
:EnterInfo
set /P path=Please Enter The Path You Want To Map(EG: \\server\folder)          
set /P z=Please Chose A drive Letter To Map.(EG Z)  
goto :CheckExist

:CheckExist
%z%:\
pause
if exist %z%:\ (
    set /P Sure=A Drive Is Already Using Drive Letter %path%:\ Are You Sure You Want To Replace It?[Y/N]
    if /I "%Sure%" EQU "Y" goto :SetDrive
    if /I "%Sure%" EQU "N" exit)
goto :SetDrive

:SetDrive
C:
dir
net use z: "%path%"
pause
```

Here is the code so far.
I'm getting an error:'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
when the script gets to the(Net use Z: "%path%")
Although the input to the command would work if i were to run it in a cmd window.

I've checked the location the script and it's running from C:\Users\%username%\ like a cmd box would default it's location too.
I'm really confused as to why it's not recognising net Use. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
set /P path=Please Enter The Path You Want To Map(EG: \\server\folder)
```

The `PATH` environment variable is already used by Windows.  It tells the command interpreter where to find programs like `net.exe`, which is in your `sys(tem32|wow64)` folder. You can't just overwrite it as you please and expect everything to work properly afterward.  You set the variable `PATH` to be the network path for the drive you want the user to map, which overwrites the actual `PATH` variable.

Solution:  Use a different variable name, like, say, `mypath`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you hit the nail on the head it's working now. I shall prefix all variables with var in future like varpath. I'll see if i can reset the environment variable too.